# R language : Check if two columns containing text are highly correlated

Tags: r, text-mining

In R, we can use the `cor` function to get the correlation between two columns but it doesn't work for non-numerical values.

I ask this because I need to preprocess some data, and I suspect 2 columns being very similar because by looking, I found that when the first column says "A", the second column always says "B" but I want to be sure that, indeed, if I know the value in the first column, I can deduce the value in the second.

If i'm not clear here's an exemple to illustrate.

```
dataframe <- read.csv(file = 'data/company_product.csv')
```

Where data/company_product.csv is a table like so

```
Company Name     Main Product       rest of the data    ...
By Apple         A phone            some_other_data     ...
By Apple         A phone            some_other_data     ...
By Microsoft     A computer         some_other_data     ...
By Nokia         A tablet           some_other_data     ...
By Nokia         A tablet           some_other_data     ...
By Nokia         A tablet           some_other_data     ...
...              ...                ...
```

As you can see in this file, the column Main Product is useless because if I know the column Company Name is "By Apple", the Main Product will always be "A phone".

This means the column Company Name is highly correlated to the column Main Product, but I do not find a simple way in R to show that

I'm not sure if the answer will be extremely trivial, or if it is a key problem in text mining, but I do not need precise correlation, all I want is a Yes/No for "Every time a value appear in first column, it will always be the same value in the second column"

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like NLP, perhaps with tokenization and classification of words. Further, the concept of correlation here seems contextual: in a macro sense, Apple, Microsoft, and Nokia are all technology companies, so that may be highly correlated. Within technology, perhaps phones do or do not correlate as well with computers/tablets.

Comment: No that's not what I meant with my exemple, I'll edit my question. What I want is that, as you can see in the exemple, every time I have "By Apple" in first, I have "A phone" in second, for all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table to assess this:

```
table(df[, 1:2])
```

giving the following which shows only one non-zero in each row and in each column showing By Apple is associated with A phone, By Microsoft is associated with A computer and By Nokia is associated with A tablet.

```
              second
first          A computer A phone A tablet
  By Apple              0       2        0
  By Microsoft          1       0        0
  By Nokia              0       0        2
```

or simply count the number of times each unique row appears:

```
aggregate(list(count = df[[1]]), df, length)
##          first     second count
## 1 By Microsoft A computer     1
## 2     By Apple    A phone     2
## 3     By Nokia   A tablet     2
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, first, second)
##          first     second n
## 1     By Apple    A phone 2
## 2 By Microsoft A computer 1
## 3     By Nokia   A tablet 2
```

or if you don't care about the count just look at the unique rows:

```
unique(df[, 1:2])
##          first     second
## 1     By Apple    A phone
## 2 By Microsoft A computer
## 4     By Nokia   A tablet
```

Visualize this as follows:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(table(df[, 1:2]))
plot(g, layout = layout.bipartite)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I need, however the "type" of data is not the same in my problem (I work with dataframe, and not lists I think), so I edited my question to fit better my problem,. You can update your answer if you want

Comment: Use df[, 1:2] instead. Have modified answer to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `table`, `xtabs` or `dcast` from `data.table` package

```
> table(df)
              second
first          A computer A phone A tablet
  By Apple              0       2        0
  By Microsoft          1       0        0
  By Nokia              0       0        2

> xtabs(~ first + second, df)
              second
first          A computer A phone A tablet
  By Apple              0       2        0
  By Microsoft          1       0        0
  By Nokia              0       0        2

> dcast(data.table::setDT(df), first ~ second)
Using 'second' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
          first A computer A phone A tablet
1:     By Apple          0       2        0
2: By Microsoft          1       0        0
3:     By Nokia          0       0        2
```

**Data**

```
dt <- data.frame(
  first = c("By Apple", "By Microsoft", "By Apple", "By Nokia", "By Nokia"),
  second = c("A phone", "A computer", "A phone", "A tablet", "A tablet")
)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've edited my question to add that there is more data in my file than just first and second column, so I dont think `table` will work (there is **alot** more data in that file) so dcast seemed a better solution, however apparently `could not find function "dcast"`, is it from a library or something ?

I found what worked, I have to use `table(dt$first, dt$second)` gave me the answer I needed, even in a dataframe with more columns

Comment: @NathanMarotte Sorry, my bad. It is from `data.table` library. You can use `library(data.table)` at the beginning of my code.

Comment: I don't think this is a base library ? I don't seem to have it and `install.packages(data.table)` doesn't work either. But as I said I found a way to make it work with `table(dt$first, dt$second)`, if you edit your answer with that i'll accept it :)

Comment: @NathanMarotte Yes, you are right. You need to install `data.table`. I updated my solution so you can see if it fits you.

Comment: It fits better but if I have more data in df (for exemple a third column), `table(df)` will use all the columns, while `table(df$first, df$second)` works best in my exemple

Comment: @NathanMarotte Then you can try `table(df[c("first","second")])`